# How to pass parameters and arguments to the loader?

Tags: webpack

loader https://github.com/mortenson/emit-file-loader

Whose code

```
const loaderUtils = require('loader-utils');

module.exports = function loader(content, map, meta) {
  const options = loaderUtils.getOptions(this);
  if (options.output) {
    const name = loaderUtils.interpolateName(this, options.output, options);
    this.emitFile(name, content);
  }
  this.callback(null, content, map, meta);
};
```

can be called like `require('emit-file-loader?{output:"somefile.css"}!../src/someFileExample.txt')`

So It can be used by passing options `output:"somefile.css"` and argument of content `../src/someFileExample.txt`
but how can I pass arguments and options calling that loader like a function in js

```
   //something like this: require('emit-file-loader')({output:"somefile.css})("somecontent")
```

So I just want to pass arguments and options calling that loader, how is that possible?